# Xcode iOS simulator allows my Cordova app to retrieve geolocation position, but watch position getting timeout error

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ios-simulator, cordova-plugins

I am using the Cordova geolocation plugin in order to detect the user's position. I am doing this like so:

```
  let positionWatcher = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
    GeolocationSuccessCallback,
    GeolocationFailCallback,
    {
      timeout: 10000,
      enableHighAccuracy: true
    }
  )
```

On the first shot it finds the position in the simulator - pointed to default California location that Xcode was setted.

Since this is a **watchPosition** method, there should be a GPS beat in 10 seconds or so. But instead of getting the position again, I get timeout error. This doesn't happening with real Android device. Not tested with real iOS device, since I don't have one.

Is Xcode's simulator doesn't support watch position for cordova geolocation plugin?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have it yet, try to add this to your config.xml file:

```
<edit-config target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
        <string>To what end I will use location service description</string>
</edit-config>
```

Always remember to do a npm install and a cordova prepare jic.

Comment: I have added all of them, like instructed here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/choosing_the_authorization_level_for_location_services/requesting_always_authorization but the watchposition just getting nothing. Maybe because there is not a real device?

Comment: It could be. I've had asimilar problem to this one in the past, but it was because I was using the javascript SDK not the ios/android, and the js sdk just does not work properly. Beyond that, could you provide the apache cordova output log?

Comment: What do you mean js SDK and not the ios/android? Could you show an example of the watchposition mechanism that you are using?
The cordova output log is simply error object with code 3, and name and message of timeout.

Comment: I want to emphasise that in first short there is a success callback. The second shot is getting failed. Also - when I go to Debug in the Xcode, and change the simulate location, the following position will be success too. Then, the next one will be failed.